# OPCUA Connection timeout in Camel Milo

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, milo

Is it possible to change the connection timeout?
I see that after 5 seconds the connection times out and it is definitely a network quality problem but if it were possible to change the timeout I could manage my need to work through a VPN.

Thanks so much

Comment: What is the camel version you're using? Can you please show your route and configuration?

Comment: camel-milo version 3.7.2 and route `milo-client:opc.tcp://Fusion4H?allowedSecurityPolicies=None&samplingInterval=1000&node=RAW(ns=4;s=GV_PcHmi.tPcHmi.tPlcToPcHmiSta.bCycleBusy)`

Comment: Maybe you can try by specifying the sessionTimeout option, which is a long.